# OP_SHA256 - Hashing the string representation

Tags: script, hash, p2sh

I'm building my own Bitcoin script interpreter for learning purposes.
I've compared my results with https://siminchen.github.io/bitcoinIDE/build/editor.html

And the script `OP_16 OP_SHA256` which results from:

```
0x4A44DC15364204A80FE80E9039455CC1608281820FE2B24F1E5233ADE6AF1DD5
```

That is the hash of the string representation of '10' (16 in hex)

Instead of the hash of the bits
(which is: `c555eab45d08845ae9f10d452a99bfcb06f74a50b988fe7e48dd323789b88ee3`)

Does the bitcoin script interpreter hash the string representation of any hex value, instead of hashing the raw number?

edit: Is it a normal behavior, to prevent things like `SHA256(1) == SHA256(01)`?

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the correct result should be `c555eab45d08845ae9f10d452a99bfcb06f74a50b988fe7e48dd323789b88ee3`.

I think this interpreter is just wrong. Looking at the source code, it has other deviations from the protocol (e.g. `OP_MUL`, which doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks! I'll avoid that one and find something else to double-check my code.